How can I force re-render of the entire page
Blazor Interactive Server app. In my MainLayout.razor, if a user is logged in, I display their avatar in the top of the page. Well below that is the @Body.
If the user changes their avatar, I need to re-render that header component, or the entire page. This change occurs when clicking Submit in the AccountProfile page. At the bottom of that page I have:
<ConfirmNavigation HasUnsavedChanges="@HasUnsavedChanges" />

And ConfirmNavigation.razor is:
<NavigationLock ConfirmExternalNavigation="@HasUnsavedChanges"
                OnBeforeInternalNavigation="OnBeforeInternalNavigation" />

Here's what I've been doing. If the avatar is changed, then I set reloadPage to true and the end of my Submit handler is:
HasUnsavedChanges = false;
await Task.Delay(reloadPage ? 20 : 1);
StateHasChanged();
await Task.Delay(reloadPage ? 20 : 1);

Navigation.NavigateTo(gotoUrl, reloadPage);

The problem is. ConfirmExternalNavigation does not see that HasUnsavedChanges is now false and prompts the user asking if they want to leave the site.
My question is not how to have NavigationLock know there's no changes. It's how do I re-render the header part of MainLayout without getting that prompt.

I assume changing the Avatar is part of their Profile.  Why not have a Profile Notification Service with a change event?

@MrCakaShaunCurtis I can call an event in the header component to tell it to re-render. But how in that event do I force a re-render?

Here's a demo doing what I think you want to achieve.  You should be able to adapt it to your needs.
A User service
public class UserService
{
    public string? AvatarName { get; private set; }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs>? AvatarChanged;

    public void ChangeAvatar(object? sender, string? name)
    {
        this.AvatarName = name;
        this.AvatarChanged?.Invoke(sender, new EventArgs());
    }
}

Registered:
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserService>();

My Avatar component:
@inject UserService UserService
@implements IDisposable

<button disabled class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">
    @(this.UserService.AvatarName ?? "No Avatar")
</button>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        this.UserService.AvatarChanged += this.OnAvatarChanged;
    }

    public void OnAvatarChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.UserService.AvatarChanged -= this.OnAvatarChanged;
    }
}

In MainLayout:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <Avatar />
            <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>

And then my edit form.  Note it uses my Blazr.EditStateTracker package to track the edit state of the model.
@page "/"
@inject UserService UserService
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@using Blazr.EditStateTracker.Components
@using Blazr.EditStateTracker
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnValidSubmit="this.OnValidSubmitAsync">
    <BlazrEditStateTracker />
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Name</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="_model.AvatarName" />
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <button disabled="@_isClean" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

<NavigationLock ConfirmExternalNavigation="_isDirty" OnBeforeInternalNavigation="this.OnLocationChanging" />
@code {
    private User _model = new();
    private EditContext? _editContext;
    private BlazrEditStateStore? _editStateStore => _editContext?.GetStateStore();
    private bool _isDirty => _editStateStore?.IsDirty() ?? false;
    private bool _isClean => !_isDirty;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // Sets up the Edit Context
        _editContext = new EditContext(_model);
    }

    private async Task OnValidSubmitAsync()
    {
        if (_isDirty)
        {
            // needed to let UI update and NavigationLock ConfirmExternalNavigation to update
            await Task.Delay(100);
            //Save
            this.UserService.ChangeAvatar(this, _model.AvatarName);

            //reset the store state
            _editStateStore?.Reset();

            NavManager.NavigateTo("/Counter");
        }
    }

    private void OnLocationChanging(LocationChangingContext context)
    {
        // Prevent navigation if the edit context is dirty
        if (_isDirty)
            context.PreventNavigation();
    }

    public class User
    {
        [TrackState] public string? AvatarName { get; set; }
    }
}

Most of this code is lifted from https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.EditStateTracker

The trick is calling StateHasChanged() - I should have thought of that. thank you
